# как добавить параметры в java в httpPost и в body и в ссылку?

Tags: java

Всем привет.

```
public void jsonSender (JSONArray jsonIn) {
        String json = String.valueOf(jsonIn);

        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(urlToTable); //работает с объектом

        StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(json, ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        httpPost.setEntity(entity);

        //httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    try {
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(response.getEntity().getContent());
        System.out.println("RESPONSE\n" + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() + ": " + response.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase());

        while(sc.hasNext()) {
            String resp =  sc.nextLine();
            int indexS = resp.lastIndexOf("\"")+2;
            int indexL = resp.lastIndexOf("</div>");
            System.out.println(resp.substring(indexS,indexL));
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

есть такой код.
подскажите, пожалуйста, как преобразовать его так чтобы добавить ещё несколько параметров в саму ссылку.(?param1=value)

```
типа example.com/books?param1=value
```

как я понимаю, необходимо как-то преобразовать переменную entity

Comment: Если в ссылку, то просто в url допишите `?param1=value1&param2=value2&param3=value3`

Comment: @Saturn1401 у меня значение параметров вариативно, хотелось бы в коде как-то это прописать

Comment: Ну засуньте их в в коллекцию, потом смотрите длину коллекции и создаете соответствующие количество параметров, или просто используйте `for-each`

Comment: Так же есть уже готовый [класс](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/net/URLEncoder.html)